# Getting back 404 responses and 400 resposes for post and Get Http requests on Spring Boot Java Project. New to spring so any advice is Appreciated

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, request-mapping

https://github.com/mikedimeji/product-service

I have linked the entire project down below if anyone wants to look over my code or attempt running it themselves. Java 17 with a Mongodb backend and a simple product controller, service, repository and request response classes to deal with user queries. The Application is building and running correctly at the correct port but for some reason its acting as if the API/product endpoint doesn't exist even though stated in requestmapping.

LOGS linked in image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bdW5.png)

Comment: Don't share screenshots. It's against the rules. Additionally, share the request body and URL that you invoke a request with.